# Java Generic Types in Method signature which are not used

Tags: java, generics, apache-kafka-streams

What is the use of specifying Generic types in the method signature when they are not getting used in the method, for instance consider the below method from Kafka Materialized:

```
public static <K, V, S extends StateStore> Materialized<K, V, S> as(String storeName) {
    Named.validate(storeName);
    return new Materialized(storeName);
}

private Materialized(String storeName) {
    this.storeName = storeName;
}
```

Here the types K,V,S are not used in the method.

[Github link for materialized class](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.java)

Comment: Don't use raw types: `return new Materialized<>(storeName);`.

Comment: K=key type, V=value type.  The result of `as` then is typed, so another method, for instance getting the key, will be type checked. The constructor `Materialized` will also declare the fields, one of which might be `K key;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use of specifying Generic types in the method signature when they are not getting used in the method

You actually are (or should be) using them in the method:

```
return new Materialized(storeName);
```

This is a raw type. It's a transcription error from [the source code you linked](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.java#L103):

```
return new Materialized<>(storeName);
```

is a shorthand for:

```
return new Materialized<K, V, S>(storeName);
```

---

But anyway, type variables on the method which are only used in the return type are used after you've called the method.

For example, creating an `ArrayList<T>` in a method allows you to add instances of `T` to the result.

```
<T> List<T> myMethod() {
  return new ArrayList<>();
} 

// At the call site:
List<String> list = myMethod();
list.add("Hello");
```

In the case of `Materialized`, this gives type information about the fields which are declared in terms of these type variables: `Serde<K> keySerde`, `Serde<V> valueSerde` and `StoreSupplier<S> storeSupplier`; Kafka can then access fields/methods on these fields which do things with specific types.